# Using LSTM to predict next number

Tags: lstm, keras

I trying to understand working of LSTM So I'm doing simple code to simulate its action.

```
x=[[i for i in range(j,j+5)] for j in range(1000)]
x=np.array(x)
x=x.reshape((1000,5,1))
y=[i+5 for i in range(1000)]
y=np.array(y)
y=y.reshape((1000,1,1))
```

Where x is timeseries like [0,1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4,5]... so on.
Where y is like 5,6... so on.

My Model is

```
model=keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.LSTM(1))
model.compile(loss="mean_absolute_error",optimizer="adam")
model.fit(x,y,epochs=500)
```

Now starting error very large like in 500s and it decreases very slow. Is it normal?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that this is because you haven't scaled your data. This is covered extensively on our website. See:https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=scale%20%5bneural-networks%5d and https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=normalize%20%5bneural-networks%5d and https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=standardize%20%5bneural-networks%5d